# How do I import a massive text file as a list in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple Word Builder type of game (where one player enters a word, and the other player enters a word starting with the last letter of the first player's word), so for it to work, I've got a list that is supposed to contain all words in the dictionary. I've got a text file that has 350k+ words, like this:

```
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
aals
aam
aani
aardvark
aardvarks
aardwolf
aardwolves
aargh
aaron
aaronic
aaronical
aaronite
aaronitic
```

and so on.
How can I import them all as a list in C#?
If there is a better way of doing it then please let me know!
I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try use [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-5.0) to read the text files lines, this will return a string array with all the entries in it and then you can either use that array by itself or pass it to a `List<string>` e.g.:

```
string[] words = File.ReadLines(@"C:\dictionary.txt");

// List<string> listOfWords = new List<string>(words);
```